# How to solve Unexpected token error in project with ReactJs and frontend-maven-plugin?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, frontend, maven-plugin

I created project using the [guide](http://justincalleja.com/2016/04/17/serving-a-webpack-bundle-in-spring-boot/). Project worked, I saw Hello World.

So I use *frontend-maven-plugin* and command `mvn clean install` to package my frontend.

But now I want to add ReactJS into this project.

My app.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return "<p>Hello from React to the World!</p>"
    }
}
const app = document.getElementById("react");
const element=<App />;
const ref = ReactDOM.render(element, app);
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "fe",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Description",
    "main": "./app",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack -p"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "react-frame-component": "^2.0.2",
        "webpack": "^3.10.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "requirejs": "^2.3.5"
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var packageJSON = require('./package.json');
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const PATHS = {
    build: path.join(__dirname, 'target', 'classes', 'META-INF', 'resources', 'webjars', packageJSON.name, packageJSON.version)
};
module.exports = {
    entry: './app/index2.js',
    output: {
        path: PATHS.build,
        filename: 'app-bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']}
};
```

index2.js:

```
import App from './app.jsx';
```

When I apply `mvn clean install`, I have the following error:

```
[INFO] app-bundle.js  827 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
[INFO]    [0] ./app/index2.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
[INFO]    [1] ./app/app.jsx 254 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[INFO]
[INFO] ERROR in ./app/app.jsx
[INFO] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (12:14)
[INFO] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
[INFO] | const app = document.getElementById("react");
[INFO] |
[INFO] | const element=<App />;
[INFO] | const ref = ReactDOM.render(element, app);
[INFO]  @ ./app/index2.js 1:0-28
[ERROR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[ERROR] npm ERR! errno 2
[ERROR] npm ERR! fe@1.0.0 build: `webpack -p`
[ERROR] npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

It sais that unexpected token is a letter before `<App />;`.

If I use quotes *const element=" < App / > ; "* it says: `Unexpected token: name (App) [app-bundle.js:263,6]`

Could you prompt please what I am missing? What is need to do to package ReactJS project using *frontend-maven-plugin*?

Answer (score 0):

you need to setup loader appropriately for React's code.
The easiest way is to use Babel:

```
 npm install -D babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-env babel-preset-react
```

And put `rules` section into your webpack config

```
module : {
    rules: [{
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader : 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            presets: ["env", "react"]
        }
    }]
}
```

This tutorial seems to be fresh enough: https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/

Comment: I left the task for a while, I will return later, thank you for answer.